# Is it possible to Hook/Filters Attachment Creation?

Tags: filters, attachments, hooks

Is it possible to hook or filter the attachment creation process?  More specifically is it possible to hook into the attachment creation so that I may parse the attachment’s filename, populate the attachment’s Meta data (title) with a filtered version of its filename?

If not, are hooks and filters planned for the media library with future updates to core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the 'add_attachment' action from wp-includes/post.php Line:3738.

It passes in the post_id and from there you can get the file name and then update the post meta with anything you need to.