# Auto Add Image Title,Caption,Alt Text,Description while uploading Images in WordPress

Tags: images, title, conditional-tags

Can anyone tell me how to auto fill/add same image title in title, caption, alt text and description while uploading any image in my WordPress Posts.

[image: desired screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

`added_post_meta` seems like a good time to hook into a new image. Not only is the default meta already set but the function gives you the `$post_id` along with `$meta_value` which holds the attachment metadata. From there you can get all the fields and set the ones you want.

```
add_action('added_post_meta', 'wpse_20151219_after_post_meta', 10, 4);

function wpse_20151219_after_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {

    // _wp_attachment_metadata added
    if($meta_key === '_wp_attachment_metadata') {

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // POST
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Change basic fields on attachment post
        wp_update_post(array(
                           'ID'           => $post_id,
                           'post_title'   => "This is a TITLE for $post_id",
                           'post_content' => "This is the DESCRIPTION for $post_id",
                           'post_excerpt' => "This is the CAPTION for $post_id",
                       ));

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // POST META
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Change ALT Text
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', "This is the ALT Text for $post_id");

        // Add Custom Field
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wpse_20121219_my_custom_meta', 'MyCustomMetaValue');

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // POST META ( ATTACHMENT METADATA )
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Change Image Metadata
        $meta_value[ 'image_meta' ] = array_merge($meta_value[ 'image_meta' ], array(
            'credit'    => 'https://black-buddha.com',
            'camera'    => 'The Best Camera EVER!',
            'copyright' => date('Y'),
            'title'     => "This is a META TITLE for $post_id",
            'caption'   => "This is a META CAPTION for $post_id",
        ));

        // Update The Image Metadata
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($post_id, $meta_value);

        // _wp_attached_file
        // _wp_attachment_metadata (serialized)
        // _wp_attachment_image_alt
        // _wpse_20121219_my_custom_meta

        $attachment_meta = get_post_meta($post_id);

        // width
        // height
        // file
        // sizes
        // image_meta
        //      aperture
        //      credit
        //      camera
        //      caption
        //      created_timestamp
        //      copyright
        //      focal_length
        //      iso
        //      shutter_speed
        //      title
        //      orientation
        //      title
        //      keywords

        $attachment_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($post_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicates, flag posts as duplicates if they are.

Answer (score 2):

> You can hook into the 'add_attachment' action from wp-includes/post.php Line:3332. **(Version 4.4)** 
>   It passes in the post_id and from there you can get the file name and then update the post meta with anything you need to.

[Reference taken from](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32839/29035)

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_125805_add_image_meta_data' );

function wpse_125805_add_image_meta_data( $attachment_ID ) {

    $filename   =   $_REQUEST['name']; // or get_post by ID
    $withoutExt =   preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
    $withoutExt =   str_replace(array('-','_'), ' ', $withoutExt);

    $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $attachment_ID,
        'post_excerpt' => $withoutExt,  // caption
        'post_content' => $withoutExt,  // description
    );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );

    // update alt text for post
    update_post_meta($attachment_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $withoutExt );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler solution, you can use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-image-attributes-from-filename-with-bulk-updater/) WordPress plugin that I made a while back.

The plugin comes with a bulk updater too that will update the image attributes for images already in your media library if you want to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

function set_image_meta_upon_image_upload($attachment_ID) {
// Verifica se há um anexo e se é uma imagem
if (wp_attachment_is_image($attachment_ID)) {
// Obtém o título do post ou página associado à imagem
$post_id = get_post_field('post_parent', $attachment_ID);
$post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

```
    // Define o título da imagem, texto alternativo, título e legenda
    if ($post_title) {
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'         => $attachment_ID,
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            //'post_excerpt' => $post_title, // Define o texto alternativo
            //'post_content' => $post_title, // Define a legenda
        ));

        // Define o texto alternativo (alternative text)
        update_post_meta($attachment_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $post_title);
    }
}
```

}
add_action('add_attachment', 'set_image_meta_upon_image_upload');