# How to modify images during upload

Tags: images, uploads

I'm developing a plugin, and, each time a user uploads an image in the media library, I'd like to modify metadata of this image.
I have tried with the hook "wp_handle_upload_prefilter" but it seems this method doesn't work.

Comment: It is hard to answer such a question. What exactly do you want to modify and ehy the use of that hook wasn't good enough, what code did you use?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212391/84219

Comment: Indeed, it was with "wp_handle_upload". Thanks a lot :)
For each image uploaded, I add metadata, with PHP (with iptcembed()) and it works fine ! :)

But is it possible to do this, for each thumbnail generated ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `attachment_fields_to_save` filter. There is nice example on codex. So instead of copying that here, I would rather like to point you towards the codex page. Please [take a look here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_save#Example_Usage). I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with "attachment_fields_to_save", but I think the function is not called, when I'm sending my image to the server :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `added_post_meta` and `update_post_meta` with the `$post_id`.  For extended properties see this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212390/84219) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1065/84219) for more image functions.

```
add_action('added_post_meta', 'wpse_20151218_after_post_meta', 10, 4);

function wpse_20151218_after_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {

    if($meta_key === '_wp_attachment_metadata') {

        // Add Custom Field
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_example_meta_key', '1234567');

        $attachment_meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
    }
}
```